# GDAL command to salvage GeotTIFF output that threw an error

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp

I used `gdalwarp` on a large NetCDF file with the intention of getting a high quality geotiff in spherical mercator. I ran the following command which took three days to complete on my laptop:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs" -r bilinear -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co BIGTIFF=YES SRTM15.nc temp.tif
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
ERROR 1: Output dataset temp.tif exists,
but some command line options were provided indicating a new dataset
should be created.  Please delete existing dataset and run again.
```

Doing some research, I think I should also have used the `-overwrite` flag. Regardless I did get a gorgeous file that is almost spherical mercator by the looks of it:

[image: screenshot of geotiff]

`gdalinfo` run on that file reports:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: temp.tif
Size is 58273, 77042
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unnamed ellipse",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["unnamed",6378137,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-20037508.342789247632027,26491625.382435433566570)
Pixel Size = (687.704979247093434,-687.716780883887168)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  lat#actual_range={-90,90}
  lat#axis=Y
  lat#long_name=latitude
  lat#standard_name=latitude
  lat#units=degrees_north
  lon#actual_range={-180,180}
  lon#axis=X
  lon#long_name=longitude
  lon#standard_name=longitude
  lon#units=degrees_east
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.7
  NC_GLOBAL#GMT_version=6.0.0 [64-bit]
  NC_GLOBAL#history=grdmath SRTM15_land_masked.nc debug/polished.unmasked.grd AND = SRTM15.nc
  NC_GLOBAL#node_offset=1
  NC_GLOBAL#title=Produced by grdmath
  z#actual_range={-10997.708984375,8627}
  z#long_name=z
  z#_FillValue=nan
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-20037508.343,26491625.382) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 88d12' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-20037508.343,-26491450.850) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 88d11'59.82"S)
Upper Right (20037123.913,26491625.382) (179d59'47.57"E, 88d12' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (20037123.913,-26491450.850) (179d59'47.57"E, 88d11'59.82"S)
Center      (    -192.215,      87.266) (  0d 0' 6.22"W,  0d 0' 2.82"N)
Band 1 Block=58273x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=nan
  Metadata:
    actual_range={-10997.708984375,8627}
    long_name=z
    NETCDF_VARNAME=z
    _FillValue=nan
```

Is there a way to pull the Spherical Mercator map out of this result, or am I back to square 1?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you think that the output is wrong? Do you mean by Spherical Mercator the EPSG:3857 coordinate system http://epsg.io/3857? Then you can simplify your command by using `-t_srs epsg:3857`. Your image is quite big and I would also use parameters `-co tiled=yes -co compress=deflate -co predictor=3`. Notice also that EPSG:3857 is not valid near the poles.

Comment: I was hoping that using the proj definition instead of `-t_srs epsg:3857` would give me the `85.06°S and 85.06°N` extent. It might work to set the SRS on this file and then set `-te`.

Comment: So I'll try `gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -te -20037508.34 -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34 temp.tif temp2.tif`